# How to search for a particular string and goto sleep if not found in perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures

I have two test cases in log file `ActivateJob` and  `GetJOBStatus` as below, my perl script currently set to `PASS` as default and it searches for `Error` in the below test cases, if it finds error in the below it makes test case as `FAIL`. For `GetJOBStatus` test case if it is `ACTIVE`  script as to sleep for couple of mins and it as to perform `GetJOBStatus` again and if it is success test case as to be passed or else fail. How can i perform sleep and search for active in `GetJOBStatus` test case.. ply help me out... thanks in advance..

==============log file===================

```
Date and Time is:Thu, 20-06-2013 06:04:19
Line 4 Command:ActivateJob(Job=Test_Abort_New1);
Answer:
ActivateFTSJobResult = Success
COMPLETED

Date and Time is:Thu, 20-06-2013 06:04:19
Line 5 Command:GetJOBStatus(Job=Test_Abort_New1);
Answer:
GetJOBStatusResult = NELabel,Status,ErrorReason,Progress,CurrentUnit,Total
TSS_320_1,ACTIVE,No Error,0,BACKUP.DSC,0
COMPLETED
```

Comment: So where is your script and what have you tried so far?

Comment: File::Tail might be useful

Answer (score 0):

In order to check for a string in a file, you have to

1. open the file using `open`
2. read the file using `<>`
3. search the file using `m//`
4. close the file

In order to sleep (for `a` seconds), you have to  `sleep(a)`

Keep in mind that unless you perform `seek` on your filehandle, you will have to `close` and then re-`open` it in order for it to reach the beginning.

As for you specific question, it appears to be implemented as an example in the [seek perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html)